# In what order should I learn linear algebra and multivariable calculus?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, self-learning

I took AP calculus in high school and I really enjoyed it, but when I got to my university I was upset that I couldn't take Calculus II as it didn't fit in my schedule. I feel kind of behind now that I'm considering pursuing an undergraduate maths degree as I realise  how much I miss doing maths.

In order to catch up and go beyond what is required, what order should I learn new maths in? I'll be taking Calculus II next semester, but I would like to do some supplementary work on my own. Can I teach myself topics in multivariable calculus and linear algebra concurrently with a Calculus II course? Which should I start with linear algebra or multivariable calculus?

Comment: The proposed duplicate target is a closed Question, and I don't think the one existing Answer given to it greatly redeems the content.  So I'm not in favor of marking this Question as a duplicate of that one.  Both are fairly old.  Perhaps we should simply close this one as well for off-topic/asking for personal advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered before.

My opinion: linear algebra is, in some ways, actually easier than calculus, and it's an important foundation for many later topics. I would suggest learning linear algebra first, and then multivariate calculus.

(Many of the applications of multivariate calculus also rely on linear algebra, whereas multivariate calculus is not required to do linear algebra. So the chain of dependencies alone should inform your decision: linear algebra first, then multivariate calc.)

Edit: I just read that you haven't done Calc II yet. Okay, definitely do linear algebra first. Doing multivariate calc without having had Calc II-exposure would probably not be a good use of your time.

Comment: Sorry for the repeat question, I tried searching for something first, but couldn't exactly find it. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Sartree sure thing :-)